# Android Development: How Can I Add Syntax Highlighting Features

Tags: android, syntax-highlighting

I want to add syntax highlighting to my application.
I'll be using syntax highlighting with PHP, HTML, CSS, XML and JavaScript.

How can I do this?
I have a TextChanger set up on my EditText, which I want to use so that the syntax highlighting process occurs when the EditText gets changed.

I'm new to Android development and only know the basics.
Thank you for reading.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, but I did start to look into using regular expressions but then I came across a post where someone said you can't and then another person said you can and I didn't know so I decided to ask on here for the easiest/recommended way of doing syntax highlighting.